How to sum C5 and C6 if B4 and B5 are within F2?

I have a row of months (B2:M2) starting from Dec 23 through Nov 24 in the following format: Dec-23...Jan-24...etc.
I also have two columns one with specific dates (B), and the other with counts associated with said date (C).
I am looking to write a formula/function that will check each date against the row of months I have and if it falls in any of those months to sum the corresponding count. Is there any way to do this?
If you look at the picture I would like for B5 to check against B2:M2 and when it gets to E2 to sum C5 on E3.
I have tried using V lookup, x lookup, and if(and( functions but no luck.
Edit: Data as a text table




12/1/23
1/1/24
2/1/24
3/1/24
4/1/24
5/1/24
6/1/24
7/1/24
8/1/24
9/1/24
10/1/24
11/1/24





0
0
0
1










3/17/2024
1













4/18/2024
2













4/23/2024
6













7/4/2024
2













8/8/2024
6













9/3/2024
5













10/27/2024
8















Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Use text tables instead. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

@KenWhite In this case, I disagree. The image clearly illustrates the data layout in the Excel grid, which is instrumental in identifying the correct formula. There is no easy way to create such a data sample in a question to be copied into the Excel grid. Even if you copy and paste data from the Excel worksheet, it pastes it as a picture here in this site, so it's not the OP's fault.

@teylyn: You can't copy/paste from that image into an Excel sheet to use for working out an answer to the question. You're free to disagree all you want, but it doesn't change the guidelines here or the majority feeling that images should be avoided. Did you read the link I posted that explains the long list of reasons not to use them? Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as a rendering issue with a UI or graphic.

@KenWhite I know about the guidelines, but there is no good way to post tabular data into a question. An image like this is helpful. What is your suggestion for posting the data sample in a way that it can be copy/pasted into Excel, then?

@KenWhite I just edited the question and posted the data from my answer as a text table. See what a mess that is? For Excel related questions, a screenshot is way better.

@teylyn: If you look at the tag wiki for Google Sheets, it explicitly says that you should not post a link to or an image of the data, but should use tables instead. There's no reason Excel should be any different. As I said, read the link I provided. Images should be avoided as much as possible for many reasons, which are all listed in that post., I'm not going to debate the guidelines or reasoning behind not wanting images. Feel free to take that discussion to [meta].

Edited the post as Markdown_Table helps to easily and copy paste as text in Excel and use by members willing to post solutions

Please use this VBA code to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.

@MayukhBhattacharya Thank you for that. Not everybody is aware that markdown even is a thing and this tool to convert Excel grid to Markdown will go into my bookmarks immediately.

Welcome Jacob! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

Consider the following screenshot and the references.
The formula starts in cell C3 with
=SUMIFS($B$5:$B$11,$A$5:$A$11,">="&C2,$A$5:$A$11,"<"&EDATE(C2,1))

and is copied to the right. Adjust the references to match your data.
In words: sum all the numbers where the date in column A is larger or equal to the date in the current column, row 3 and at the same time less than the date in the current column, row 3 plus 1 month.

